# JMS ReplyTo - How does it work?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms

The JMS API allows messages to declare a replyTo `Destination` instance. (i.e. the superclass of `Queue`, `Topic`). A service could then send a reply message to the sender using this queue.

Are there any restrictions on what `Destination` can be set as a ReplyTo value? That seems unlikely to work, for the service may not even have any network route to the defined `Destination` and therefore could not return any message. Does JMS somehow assert the validity (reachability) of a provided `Destination`? Or is it simply up to the service to try to respond on the given `Destination` and fail if necessary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Scenario 1**

In this scenario the `Destination` is pre-configured and hence proven to work. There is not much value to set this destination as a value for `JMSReplyTo` header as the receiver might already know about the existence of this pre-configured destination.

**Scenario 2**

In this scenario the sender creates a **temporary** Destination and receiver will know about this only by calling `getJMSReplyTo()` method on the received `Message`. This kind of establishes a private channel between sender and receiver. [Read this nice article](http://onjava.com/onjava/2007/04/10/designing-messaging-applications-with-temporary-queues.html) on pros and cons of temporary destinations.

Sample code

```
Queue tempQueue = qSession.createTemporaryQueue();
TextMessage request = qSession.createTextMessage();
request.setJMSReplyTo(tempQueue);
QueueReceiver qReceiver = qSession.createReceiver(tmpQueue);
Message response = qReceiver.receive();
```

**edit:** Add a web archive link for the original [http://onjava.com/onjava/2007/04/10/designing-messaging-applications-with-temporary-queues.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20180506203104/http://www.onjava.com:80/pub/a/onjava/2007/04/10/designing-messaging-applications-with-temporary-queues.html)

Comment: Thanks. Do both the sender and receiver need to be using the same JNDI service?

Comment: @Synesso added a link to the article that will answer your question.

Comment: Aha "Static Destinations ... Have well-known identities (resolved with JNDI) with both consumers and producers". Thanks again.

Comment: @Aravind Before writing my own answer I wanted to point out that on some JMS brokers, your code may not work unless the the Publisher and Consumer are using the same Session in which the Temp Topic was created. This is why I fought so hard for the JBossMQ to allow the AS to support an option to autocreate any referenced runtime queues that had not been created before hand, like AMQ, RabbitMQ, etc. JBoss DID follow the spec but it's not pragmatic as this likely fails if its a broker to broker topology. This Question is still highly relevant.

Comment: The link in the answer is dead, can someone update it?  (and by the way it's always nice to have a summary of an external link in an answer)